# Rails Migration Column Type Polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, types, migration

I've got a little situation that I'd like to take care of, but I don't even know if it's possible.

In my app, I have one model that can take a parameter value, this parameter can be either a string or an integer or a boolean.

Instead of doing two string column (in my migration) with one labeled as "type" (the type - really !) and the other labeled as "value" (for the... value ! Yes !) i was wondering if it was possible that there is only the column value remaining, with polymorphics types in there.

The Model represent a property on a taks. Theses properties can be : is this task's open (type "boolean" and value "true" for exemple) ? Does this task has a percentage (type "integer", value "20") ? Note that the table also have a column name.

Comment: It seems weird to me that a value can be 3 different types. Can you clarify an example of what you are using that value for so that we can provide a better answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Polymorphism in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) is more about associations where the class of the related item is unknown - not database columns with a dynamic type.

While is possible to implement a dynamic column in a relational database using two string columns `value` and `value_type` and use a custom getter to typecast value its going to get really messy. Another possibility is to use a something like a HSTORE or JSON column type but again do you really need it? Is there a better way to structure your business logic than trying to jam everything into a single column?

I'm guessing that what you may be looking for is something like an [enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to denote the state of your model.

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :open, :closed, :pending, :active ]
end
```

This would use an integer column named `status`.

If you wanted to store additional information it would be prudent to use an additional database column. Like if you want to monitor the progress you would create an integer database column named `tickets.progress`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very usefull. However, i decided to go with a serializer.The fact that the type of my data is the same at the "output" that it was at the "input" is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For your answer, yes it is possible, but don't do it that way. 
It is possible to use string for all different cases:

- "integer:100", "integer:23", etc.
- "boolean:true", "boolean:false", etc.

you will need to identify each data type(use concat)and convert to a right type and only then you can use the value.

**But it is completely wrong and its implementation is going to be very complicated**.
 I strongly recommend not to use this example or something similar.

 
**I think that this is a wrong database structure.** 
In general, if you have a case in which you have a column that you think can contain more than one data type - something is wrong in your database and you should make a 'redesign' of your database. 
**Usually the best practice is to separate to different columns.**
 In your case, your column can get different types, each type represents different information. I think your table should have these columns:

1. status_id - will reference to another table, Status that will contain all possible statuses(if there are more than 2 options).
2. progress/percentage - integer.

My answer isn't relevant for relational databases.